# Is it possible to create a table of views in oracle

Tags: oracle

It might be a stupid question, but as oracle allows to create table of different objects, I thought maybe it is possible to create a table of views.

I need to generate many, many views (which will be pivoting some table). Each view will have different column names.
I do not want to pollute the namespace with hundreds or thousands of views named 
`schema.xls_import_id_1234_sheet_0`.

Is it possible to create a table of views? And then query them with something like

```
select * from table(
    select a_view from xls_sheet_views where xls_id = 1234 and sheet_no = 0)
```

Or maybe a way to store just a query as varchar2 type, and some method to execute it automaticly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot create a table of views.

Depending on the precise business problem you are trying to solve, potentially you could implement the logic in pipelined table functions in a package rather than having thousands of views.  If you have so many views because you are creating a separate object for every combination of attributes that you might pivot by, it may make sense to use a pipelined table function that accepts some parameters rather than having hundreds of views.  Or it might make sense to have a few procedures in a package that return a `SYS_REFCURSOR`.

In general, if you want to use a pipelined table function, you would want to know the structure of your result.  You can get tricky, though, by making use of polymorphism in Oracle object types.  You can declare a single object type, derive a number of subtypes and then return instances of the subtypes from a pipelined table function defined on the parent type. Adrian Billington has an excellent example of this sort of [flexible pipelined table function](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=420).  You can get even crazier, though, with the Data Cartridge framework and develop a [pipelined table function that returns an arbitrarily structured result](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=422).  Now, just because you *can* do something like this, I certainly wouldn't advocate actually doing it without a lot of careful consideration.  The need to have this level of dynamic code for something as common as pivoting some data would make me strongly suspect that you need to take a step back and look at the architecture of the system.

Comment: Could you elaborate about how to define a pipelined function without specifying an explict return row type?